# Read XLSX data in groovy and pass the values to soapui request in soapui free tool

Tags: soapui

Scenario is I have many rows and columns in XLSX file, I want to read the data and also get data in the cell to pass those values to soapUI request

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple java excel connection code to replicate this. Please follow below code:-

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;

def projectPath = context.expand('${projectDir}') //Where your project resides main project properties 
def path = projectPath + "/userInput.xls" //your inputsheet name

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path)

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Sheet Name")
int rows = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
log.info(rows)
```

After that use basic java code to read columns and traverse through it using Iterator. An once it is done, get the required data which you want to pass in request and put inside properties testStep and from there go to soapui request and parameterize all the data using in-built GetData method.